# Tkinter window stop autostart

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to build a small window to interact with my python shop-system with tkinter. But if i start the Window the code also autostart my simpledialog window. I think its because of my, litte special, way to start the simpledialog window.

Can anybody help me how to start the window the correct way by giving the product_data to the next function?

```
class Window:
    product_1 = Product(price=5.40, stock=200, name="Nudel", id="1")
    product_2 = Product(price=5.30, stock=15, name="Steine", id="2")
    product_3 = Product(price=4.30, stock=200, name="Tassen", id="3")

    shop_products = [product_1, product_2, product_3]
    cart_products = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = Tk()
        self.main.title = "Shop Menu"
        self.label = Label(self.main, text="Welcome!")
        self.products_button = Button(self.main, text="shop", command=self.build_shop_window)
        self.cart_button = Button(self.main, text="cart", command=self.build_cart_window)
        self.add_product_button = Button(self.main, text="add")
        self.remove_product_button = Button(self.main, text="remove")
        self.label.pack()
        self.products_button.pack()
        self.cart_button.pack()
        self.add_product_button.pack()
        self.remove_product_button.pack()

    def add_to_cart(self, product):
        print(product.id)
        quantity = simpledialog.askfloat("Quantity", "Wie oft möchten Sie das Produkt kaufen?", parent=self.window1)
        if int(product.stock) <= quantity:
            messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Shop', message = 'Leider haben wir die geforderte Menge des Produktes ' + str(product.name) + " nicht auf Lager. Bitte bestellen Sie zunächst eine kleinere Menge, neue Ware ist bereits auf dem Weg!")
            #Message an Betreiber, dass Produkt bestellt werden muss (Abhängig von Verkaufsstatistik)



    def build_shop_window(self):
        self.window1 = Tk()
        self.window1.title("Shop")
        self.label = Label(self.window1, text="Shop")
        self.label_1 = Label(self.window1, text=str(self.product_1.name) + str(self.product_1.price) + "€ Noch verfügbar: " + str(self.product_1.stock))
        self.button_1 = Button(self.window1, text ="In den Warenkorb", command=self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[0]))
        self.label_2 = Label(self.window1, text=str(self.product_2.name) + str(self.product_2.price) + "€ Noch verfügbar: " + str(self.product_2.stock))
        self.button_2 = Button(self.window1, text ="In den Warenkorb", command=self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[1]))
        self.label_3 = Label(self.window1, text=str(self.product_3.name) + str(self.product_3.price) + "€ Noch verfügbar: " + str(self.product_3.stock))
        self.button_3 = Button(self.window1, text ="In den Warenkorb", command=self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[2]))

        self.label.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.label_1.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.button_1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.label_2.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.button_2.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.label_3.grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.button_3.grid(row=3,column=1)

    def run(self):
        self.main.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot!

Tom

Comment: this is not for fixing errors but dont use `Tk()` more than once so u can change `self.window1 = Tk()`  to `self.window1 = Toplevel()` and dont have to call `mainloop()` for it too

Comment: im not into using classes with tkinter, but im pretty sure using `Tk()` more than once is not good

Comment: yeah worked finaly, thanks. But as you said, the "autostart" problem is going on... In th given code, did i used the right way to start the function "add_to_cart" with the button?

Comment: oh wait, u have to use `lambda` wen ur passing in arguments for buttons, like `command=lambda: self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[0])` if still not working, try removing the `self`. And also do the same for all the buttons that takes arguments

Comment: thanks a lot, just forgot about the lamda function. worked finaly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing out `lambda` when you are passing in arguments to functions for
your buttons,

Changing your buttons to the following shall fix the error:

```
self.button_1 = Button(self.window1, text ="In den Warenkorb", command=lambda: self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[0]))
self.button_2 = Button(self.window1, text ="In den Warenkorb", command=lambda: self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[1]))
self.button_3 = Button(self.window1, text ="In den Warenkorb", command=lambda: self.add_to_cart(self.shop_products[2]))
```

Furthermore as an advice, use `Tk()` only for the main window and not more than once, so every other `Tk()` other than the main window should be replaced with `Toplevel()` and no need to say `mainloop()` for toplevels, like:

```
self.window1 = Toplevel()
```

Hope it solved the error, and happy coding :D

Cheers